# When is the sum of sets to be equal to the union of sets?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

**Problem:**

Define  $A+B=\{a+b : a\in A, b\in B\}$. Suppose that the sum of overlapping convex cones $A_1, A_2, A_N\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{d}$ is such that $\mathbf{0}\in A_1\cap A_2\cap \ldots\cap A_N$.
$$S =  A_1+A_2+\ldots+A_N=A_1\cup A_2\cup \ldots\cup A_N,$$
where $S$ is a subspace. Under what conditions on the sets is this possible?

**Context:**

We know that the union of subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ is a subspace iff one of them contains the other subspaces. I am curious about what happens if we relax the subspace constraint and replace it with convex cones. Since the convex cone assumption did not help me, I added one more condition (on the sum). Still, I am unable to solve it!

Comment: when all elements act like 0, because 0 is the additive identity meaning we can add it to anything and not change it.

Comment: I didn't follow. Could do you explain that using the orthant example?

Comment: never hear that term. but $\{0,...\}$ and $\{0,...\}$ give element sums including all values, so they give the union as a subset. only if other elements act like 0 will there not be more. okay or they are both infinite...

Comment: You mean to say $A_1=S$ and $A_i=\{\mathbf{0}\}$?

Comment: `setbinop((a,b)->a+b,[2,3,4],[3,4,0])` in pari gp online may shed some light.

Comment: The sum of the $A_N$ is the smallest convex cone containing all of them, so the condition is equivalent to simply saying that the union is itself a convex cone (or just convex, depending on what you mean by "cone").

Comment: The union is a subspace by assumption